# CMD/BAT Поиск строк и запись в файл

Tags: cmd

Здравствуйте. Нужен код который, будет искать строки из длинного списка и записывать найденный результат в текстовый файл. При повторном запуске нужно дозаписывать, а не создавать файл заново. Очень желательно, чтобы поисковые слова можно было указывать списком, а не через пробел. Код, который ниже, прекрасно работает, но искомые слова приходится указывать в одну строчку через пробел, а при повторном запуске программы файл с результатами перезаписывается.

```
FINDSTR /L "слово1 слово2 слово3" text.txt > found.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы дозаписать в файл, используйте оператор `>>`. Оператор `>` заменяет файл.

Не очень понятно, что такое "слова списком". Если вам нужен нормальный синтаксис и нормальный функционал, просто используйте PowerShell или VBScript. Не нужно мучаться с устаревшей технологией, которая на винде никогда не была в почёте.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Списком - это каждое слово с новой строки.

Comment: А какую технологию лучше всего использовать, чтобы обрабатывать очень большие файлы? Нужно производить поиск строк в файлах по 100 - 200гб, и делать это быстро.

Comment: @Юрий Технологию использовать любую по вкусу. При работе с файлами вы с большим запасом упрётесь в скорость носителя информации. В винде основным средством для скриптов и автоматизации можно считать PowerShell, который продвигается как замена CMD. VBScript никуда не делся. Если вы ничем не ограничены, то можно использовать Python, Perl, JavaScript и вообще любой язык.